# Double Not Exists SQL Logic Explanation

Tags: mysql, sql, querying

There are 2 tables, one called drinkers with a column of names, another called frequents which has 2 columns, drinker and bars (that they frequent).

I have a query that answers this statement:

```
Drinkers who frequent all bars
```

or wordred differently:

```
Drinkers such that there aren’t any bars that they don’t frequent
```

Here is the resulting query:

```
SELECT d.name
FROM drinkers d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT b.name
    FROM bars b
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM frequents f
        WHERE f.drinker = d.name
        AND f.bar = b.name
        )
    )
```

I am having the hardest time following the logic when two `NOT EXISTS` are used.
How do I understand these types of queries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try to unfold these kind of queries from the inside out. So, start with the last sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM frequents f
WHERE f.drinker = d.name
AND f.bar = b.name
```

Here you are selecting the clients of a specific bar having a particular name: in other words, you are checking if this particular drinker goes to this bar. So now:

```
SELECT b.name
FROM bars b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM frequents f
    WHERE f.drinker = d.name
    AND f.bar = b.name
)
```

could be seen as something like

```
SELECT b.name
FROM bars b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (this particular client in it)
```

Here you are selecting all bars that don't have this person as a client. Therefore, you end up with something like

```
SELECT d.name
FROM drinkers d
WHERE NOT EXISTS (any bar without this guy as a client)
```

And I think at this point the query should seem clear: select all drinkers for which there is no bar without them.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you absolutely need to go through those *NOT EXISTS* loops, since you could very well do something like this

```
SELECT d.name
FROM drinkers d 
INNER JOIN frequents f ON f.drinkerName = d.name
GROUP BY d.name
HAVING COUNT(distinct barName) = 
    (SELECT COUNT(distinct barName) 
     from frequents
)
```

Basically, you count the total number of bars, then you compare each person's number of frequented bar to that number. Adding those *distinct* clauses in COUNT allows you to ignore duplicates.